# difference between lcds and fds

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe

Just want to clear a very basic doubt am having for quite some time.

- Is LCDS and FDS the same

I am confused with both these terms. This might be a simple doubt, but still I would like to clear this. Please help.

Regards,
Anoop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex Data Services (FDS) was the old name.  Now it's called [LiveCycle Data Services ES2](http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/dataservices/).

Comment: That's a great answer... Thanks James for clearing the doubt :)